# Given R^2 for linear regression y ~ x1, and y ~ x2, what will be the range of R^2 of y ~ x1 + x2?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, r-squared

I was asked this question during an interview.

I understand that , $R^2$ is

$$1-{{||{y-y^{fit}}||} \over\ {||y-y^{mean}||}}$$

Intuitively, the $R^2$ of the multi-regression should be higher than each individual $R^2$, and it should be affected by how $x_1$ and $x_2$ correlate. If $x_1 == x_2$, the $R^2$ should be totally different from the situation when $x_1$ and $x_2$ has no correlation.

Can anyone share some thoughts how to solve this problem ?

Comment: For a lower bound, consider if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are perfectly correlated (perhaps one in meters and the other in centimeters).

Comment: and for an upper bound, consider the case where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are perfectly uncorrelated and explain the response perfectly.

Comment: The preceding two comments trivialize the problem by ignoring the information about the univariate $R^2:$ a good range will (1) depend on those two value of $R^2$ and (2) offer the smallest possible values.  It may be helpful to frame the question as one about the relationship between any three vectors in a space of at most three dimensions (that is, the space spanned by $x_1,$ $x_2,$ and $y$), which enables it to be visualized.

Answer (score 5):

First, notice that the $R^2$ for $\mathbb E[y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2$ cannot be lower than $R^2$ for $\mathbb E[y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1$ or $\mathbb E[y] = \beta_0 + \beta_2x_2$, since the model with both variables could always give either $\beta_1=0$ or $\beta_2=0$ and achieve that $R^2$ of the other simple linear regression.

Thus, there is a lower bound of $\max\{R^2_1, R^2_2\}$.

Also, it could be that the two variables perfectly explain $y$, such as $y = x_1 + x_2$.

Thus, the upper bound of $R^2$ can be achieved.

In conclusion, the $R^2$ for $\mathbb E[y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2$ will be between $\max\{R^2_1, R^2_2\}$ and $1$.